# Motor control in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to generate electromotive force (emf) or BLDC motor from rotor position theta based on this equation.

[image]

my simulink model is like in figure 2

[image]

and this is my coding that I have write

---

```
function fa  = mymotor(theta)
%this matlab file will generate back emf of phase a
%function [fa]= mymotor(theta)
%inputs: theta -- rotor position in rad
%output: fa -- function of rotor position of phase a
pi=3.14159;
theta=0<theta<2*pi;

if(0<theta<pi/6)
    fa=(6/pi)*theta;

elseif(pi/6<theta<5*pi/6)
    fa=1;

elseif(5*pi/6<theta<7*pi/6)
    fa=-(6/pi)*theta + 6;

elseif(7*pi/6<theta<11*pi/6)
    fa=-1;

else
   fa=(6/pi)*theta - 12;

end
```

---

```
function fb  = mymotor(theta)
%this matlab file will generate back emf of phase b
%function [fb]= mymotor(theta, E)
%inputs: theta -- rotor position in rad
%output: eb -- function of rotor position of phase b
pi=3.14159;
theta=0<theta<2*pi;

if(0<theta<pi/2)
    fb=-1;

elseif(pi/2<theta<5*pi/6)
    fb=(6/pi)*theta - 4;

elseif(5*pi/6<theta<9*pi/6)
    fb=1;

elseif(9*pi/6<theta<11*pi/6)
    fb=-(6/pi)*theta + 10;

else
    fb=1;

end
```

---

```
function fc  = mymotor(theta)
%this matlab file will generate back emf of phase c
%function [fc]= mymotor(theta, E)
%inputs: theta -- rotor position in rad
%        E -- product of ke times wref
%output: ec -- function of rotor position of phase b
pi=3.14159;
theta=0<theta<2*pi;

if(0<theta<pi/2)
    fc=1;

elseif(pi/6<theta<pi/2)
    fc=-(6/pi)*theta + 2;

elseif(pi/2<theta<7*pi/6)
    fc=-1;

elseif(7*pi/6<theta<9*pi/6)
    fc=(6/pi)*theta - 8;

else
    fc=1;

end
```

---

There are no errors, but I don't get the right response from the motor.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I assume you checked that theta is in radians. We can not help here. The only think we could help with would be checking that you wrote your equations correctly, but even if you did, we have no idea where those equations come from. What do you mean you don't get the rigth response? How do you know what response those equations will give? Can you show us?

Comment: This looks wrong to me: `theta=0<theta<2*pi`